# Unknown class _TtC10MMCardView8CardView in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, xcode8, uicollectionviewcell

The project is here https://github.com/utsav475908/StackRepository/tree/master/Somethinge22

I am registering a custom collectionviewcell in viewDidLoad, I am getting this error. Please help. [image]

I have tried like module mapping . inheritance of my collectionviewcell in File Owner. I have done what earlier people have faced, with no resolution. Attaching the snapshot for the same.
[image]

Comment: I have tried in viewWillAppear too as well as seen in the image..There is some other issues which is not helping me finding bug. Not even exception breakpoint.

Comment: click obn collection View Cell and what class is there, not on owner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your project, and found the problem is in Main.Storyboard. Actually, the module `MMCardView` is not existed anymore:

[image]

Change it to the following setting to fix problem(just **remove old class and module name**, and **fill the class name "CardView" again**, the right Module will be added automatically):
[image]